# XML Parser doesn't seem to work in my javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I'm trying to read my XML file from a JavaScript file.

The XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pct>
    <occ>
        <morphology>A</morphology>
        <morphology>B</morphology>
        <morphology>C</morphology>
    <morphology>D</morphology>
    </occ>
    <life>
        <morphology>X</morphology>
        <morphology>Y</morphology>
        <morphology>Z</morphology>
    </life>
</pct>
```

And here is the Javascript code snippet:

```
function loadDynamic(){
xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("data.xml");
    ......
}

function loadXMLDoc(filename){
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",filename,true);
xmlhttp.send();
return xmlhttp.responseXML;
}
```

Now I know my loadXMLDoc function is working because I see my XML doc in xmlhttp.responseXML when I check on Chrome Console. But my xmlDoc is always null.

I'm clueless as to where I am going wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!

Comment: Hold on - so you can see it in `responseXML`, but by the time it's returned to `xmlDoc` it's null?

Comment: yes. That is what is happening

Comment: same thing is happening even when i pass a text file instead of an xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that when you inspect it, you're giving the call time to complete, but when your program just runs it's returning the responseXML before the call has completed (so it's still null).

You can prevent this by turning off the asynchronous request - basically, just change your true to false:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
```

Comment: awesome! that worked! and Ive been at it for hours! Thanks a ton! :D

Comment: Making ajax request synchronous is extremely bad practice because I defeats the purpose of the AJAX making UI frozen.

Comment: Indeed, but that was the issue.